# NodeJs throws an EADDRINUSE error

Tags: node.js

server_02.js:

```
    var http = require("http");
function start() {
  function onRequest(request, response) {
      console.log("Request received.");
      response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
      response.write("Hello World");
      response.end();
  }

  http.createServer(onRequest).listen(8888);

  console.log("Server has started.");

}

exports.start = start;
```

index.js:

```
var server = require("./server_02");
server.start();
```

throwed error:

```
events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::8888
```

Where I was wrong?
I'm following a simple book guide for beginner o.O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means some other process is already listening on that port. You might try executing something like `sudo netstat -nlp | grep 8888` if you're on *nix.

Comment: But I wrote "killall node" before to run that code...

Comment: I see, I forgot to put "-9" between "killall" and "node", silly me.